# How do I connect to Google's App Engine Shared Memache service from a Rails standard environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memcached

I have a Rails app running in Google Cloud's App Engine standard environment. I'd like to be able to connect to the Memcache service provided by App Engine, but I cannot figure out how to connect to it. I've got my `config/environments/production.rb` set to use the memcache store:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, ENV['MEMCACHE_SERVERS']
```

What value do I set for the `MEMCACHE_SERVERS` variable? I cannot find this anywhere in the Google Cloud Console or the docs. The only tidbit I can find is "Memcache is not supported for flex environments", which this is not using. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Memcache service is not recommended any more. I have found that it was available only for Python 2.7, Java 8 and PHP 5.

You can find it documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache)

I hope it will help somehow...